# htaccess Regex 301 Redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I'm having a hard time getting a permanent redirect to work.  I would like this to happen, using regular expressions.

OLD URL: https://example.com/olddir/other_name_here/123456/garbage.jpg

NEW URL: https://example.com/newdir/other-name-here-123456/

Note the change from underscores to dashes and the fact that I'm throwing the extra bits away after the numeric string.  I've tried this but it isn't working (page doesn't exist and still getting a 404):

```
RewriteRule ^/olddir/other_name_here/([0-9]{6})/.+ /newdir/other-name-here-$1/ [R=301,L]
```

I have a few hundred names in the "other_name_here" directory location, so if I could dynamically change underscores to hyphens that would be good but not necessary.  olddir and newdir are actual names and can be hardcoded.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: have you added the following lines to your `.htaccess` file and before the `RewriteRule`?

Line 1: `Options +FollowSymLinks`
Line2: `RewriteEngine On`

also add a `$` after your ` `([0-9]{6})/.+`

Last but not least, are you sure that your new URL does exist (the file is available on the server)?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following actions:

- If not present in your `.htaccess` add the following 2 lines before your `RewriteRule`:

  ```
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  ```
- Change your regex in the following way by adding a `$`:

  ```
  RewriteRule ^/olddir/other_name_here/([0-9]{6})/.+$ /newdir/other-name-here-$1/ [R=301,L]
  ```
- Try to access to your new URL pages directly and confirm that they are accessible.

Finally, I would recommend this website for details about the `.htaccess` detailed configuration: https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^olddir/other_name_here/(\d+)/.+$ newdir/other-name-here-$1/ [R=301,L]
```